# Create wpf button with an image and a text

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, styles

I would like to create a button template in order to display an image and a label in the button.
I thiking about use an horizontal stackpanel on the button.

I don't succeed to display the label.

**Here is my template :**

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="BoutonImageEtTexte">
<Button Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="90" Height="27" >
    <Button.Content>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Border CornerRadius="3">
                <ContentPresenter/>
                <Border.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#58585a" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DegradeCouleurTheme}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Border.Style>
            </Border>
            <Label>
                <Label.Content>Fichiers joints</Label.Content>
                <Label.Foreground>white</Label.Foreground>
                <Label.VerticalAlignment>center</Label.VerticalAlignment>
                <Label.HorizontalAlignment>center</Label.HorizontalAlignment>
            </Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button.Content>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

**Here is my call of this template :**

```
<Grid Margin ="10,180,10,14">
            <Button Template="{StaticResource BoutonImageEtTexte}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,0,0,0"> 
                <Image Source="ToolBar_FicJoints.png" />
            </Button>
        </Grid>
```

**Here is another method with a Textbox instead a Label**

```
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="BoutonImageEtTexte">
    <Button Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="90" Height="27" >
        <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Border CornerRadius="3">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#58585a" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DegradeCouleurTheme}" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                </Border>
                    <TextBlock Text="LabelText" />
                </StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</ControlTemplate>
```

My problem is i see onl my image, and not my label specified in the template.
Anyone could help me please ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Your concept is totally off. If you want to create a control template of a button to take in more than one item as content, you have to create an extra dependency property.

Comment: Could you please me give me an example in order to doing this ?

Comment: This seems like a good post... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knom/archive/2007/10/31/wpf-control-development-3-ways-to-build-an-imagebutton.aspx

Comment: This link is nice ! Thanks ! But, it uses c# code, and not full xaml :-(

Comment: There is nowhere in you post that you specify only use xaml and you tagged this question with c# so you shouldn't comment that the link is not what you wanted. Creating dependency properties to handle the image source and the text content is the preferred way to be able to data bind using MVVM.

Answer (score 12):

A TextBlock fits your needs better than a label. If you don't use the extra label functionality (such as target, object content), stick with a good 'ole TextBlock.

If you want to disable all button styling and only have an image and label in the button (note, this nullifies mouseover/mousedown effects, but you can provide the logic in triggers):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="SimpleButton">
    <ContentPresenter/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Usage:

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource SimpleButton}"> 
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="ToolBar_FicJoints.png" />
        <TextBlock Text="LabelText" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

If you just want the Image/TextBlock in a normal styled button, it is even easier:

```
<Button> 
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="ToolBar_FicJoints.png" />
        <TextBlock Text="Fichiers joints" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: I tried, but my textbox displayed out of the button, have you an idea ? I edit my first post with the TxtBoxMedthod :) Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

Use canvas as follows.

```
<Button Height="50" Width="150" >
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Canvas>
                                    <Image Source="./Images/Cancel.png"/>
                                    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="8" Text="Cancel" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="18"/>
                                </Canvas>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                     </Button>
```

You can adjust `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` as per your requirements. I hope this one will help you as it will display Textblock on top of the image.